# XWayland Broken

Tags: wayland

I have installed Visual Studio Code on Debian 13 (testing) with KDE/Wayland and it doesn't work properly. When using `--enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland` it appears properly but crashes very often and is very glitchy at the point where it is unusable. How to make it work under wayland?

**Edit: All XWayland apps do that, so it's not a VSCode related issue. After a reboot XWayland apps work prefectly for a while, then suddently XWayland crashes and when I open that app again it shows like in the picture (content is missalinged with the window). In a live usb stick running Ubuntu 23.10/GNOME/Wayland, VSCode and any XWayland application work fine.**

[image]

Comment: seems to me, the point of failure could be 1. VS Code, 2. Debian 13 (testing), 3. KDE/Wayland - have you tried Gnome/Wayland and/or Debian Stable?

Comment: the problem is xwayland driver I think, because when forced using ozone, everything works well..